# How do get value of an independent controlled component in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

I'm try to get the selected value from the datepicker of the antd. To get a value from the datepicker of the antd, I used it because it was said that I had to use the controller.

```
import React from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import moment from "moment"; 

// The module moment.js is large, so I made it an independent component.
export default function InputDatePicker({ name, date, control }) {
  const dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
  const initialValue = undefined;
  return (
    // I tried to use the controller inside the InputDatePicker component, 
    // but it does not recognize the value.
    // <Controller
    //   as={<DatePicker format={dateFormat} />}
    //   name="installDate"
    //   type="date"
    //   control={control}
    // />
    <DatePicker name="installDate" format={dateFormat} />
  );
}
```

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

export default function SubmitForm() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control, watch } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      // Input Other components are simply components that receive and render values.
      <InputOther
            label="date"
            component={
              <Controller
                as={<InputDatePicker defaultValue="" />}
                name="date"
                defaultValue=""
                control={control}
              />
            }
       />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

However, this will only return the default "", even if the value is selected. How can I get the value of an independent datpicker component? I'd be very grateful if you could tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

### I Don't Know Which Component You Used But I Prefered Following Approche:

Step 1:

```
npm install react-datepicker --save
```

Step 2:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

const Example = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```

### & This Will Work For ME.

Comment: Thank you @yash sanghavi. I learned from your code and also my error being resolved. Thank you for including the code.